# How to represent a condition in DCGAN?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network, multimedia

I have an encoded vector of dimension (64, ) that serves as a condition for the generation of an Image. The image generation network is a convolutional neural network. How can I represent this condition of dimension (64, ) in generator and discriminator for the successful generation of images?
I have tried reshaping the (64, ) into (8 * 8 * 1) and added this as a channel to the noise for generation in the generator. And for the discriminator, I have converted (64, ) into (256 * 256 * 1) and added it as a channel to the original image for classifying as real or fake. Is this a correct method or am I missing something. Please check the below code. I am working on the problem of text-to-image generation.
The architecture that I have used is:

Generator:

```
noise = Input(shape = (NOISE_DIM, ))
label = Input(shape = (ENCODED_DIM, ))

gen = Reshape((8, 8, 2))(noise)

li = Reshape((8, 8, 1))(label)    

inputs = Concatenate()([gen, li])    #Output_Shape = (8, 8, 3)


x = Conv2DTranspose(512, (5,5), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(inputs)
x = Activation("tanh")(x)                    #Output_Shape = (16, 16, 512)
x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (5,5), strides=(4,4), padding='same')(x)
x = Activation("tanh")(x)                    #Output_Shape = (64, 64, 256)
x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (5,5), strides=(4,4), padding='same')(x)
x = Activation("tanh")(x)                    #Output_Shape = (256, 256, 128)
features = Conv2D(3, (7,7), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
                                             #Output_Shape = (256, 256, 3)
model = Model([noise, label], features)
model.summary()
```

Discriminator:

```
label = Input(shape = (ENCODED_DIM, ))
x = Dense(256 * 256 * 1, activation = "tanh")(label)
x = Reshape((256, 256, 1))(x)

features = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
inputs = Concatenate()([features, x])       #Output_shape = (256, 256, 4)

x = Conv2D(512, (5,5), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(inputs)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (5,5), strides=(4,4), padding='same')(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (5,5), strides=(4,4), padding = 'same')(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
valid = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model([features, label], valid)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = "adam")
model.summary()
```

Please help in the architecture and point out the mistakes because the image generated is random and garbage.

Comment: Check Conditional GAN (CGAN), it's already been thought out